# Upgrade Python version in Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

I am following this guide:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18641/Upgrade-Python-2-7-6-to-Python-2-7-10-on-Linux-Mint-OS.html

It says to do

```
make install
```

When I do that it says:

[image]

If I do: `su` then enter passowrd and then `make install`
same error appears.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you look at the `makefile`, what does it say?

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. That said, why do you want to install from source? Why don't you use the builtin tools to update your installation?

Comment: @Simon `make file` gives same error.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I just want to update python, I used the first guide I found. This is a virtual machine I just need to test something specific.

Comment: The `make` command uses a file called `makefile` to tell it how to build the software. If there is no file of that name in the directory, I expect an earlier step in the process has been missed.

Comment: @Simon I did exactly what the guide said. The path I'm at is: Downloads\Python-2.7.11  same as the guide. The files there are what I extracted from the python pack.

Comment: Using the first guide you find may not be the best of all ideas.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Can you specify what is wrong?

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You should avoid installing packages from source unless you have a compelling reason. Instead, use the system's package manager to upgrade.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably following wrong steps. Before installing the Python from the source you should install required packages and configure source accordingly. So I suggest you to follow the steps:

Install Required Packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

Download and extract Python 2.7.10

```
$ cd /usr/src
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz
$ tar xzf Python-2.7.10.tgz
```

Compile Python Source

```
$ cd Python-2.7.10
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make altinstall
```

Check the Python Version

```
$ python2.7 -V
```

*Source: http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/*